# Migration is required, but the schema version has been bumped up?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm suddenly experiencing a huge amount of crashes from users that has updated to the latest version of my app. The app uses realm and I have used realm since the release 2 years ago. The latest version had a schema change, and I bumped up the schema version in the migration block as I normally do. However, according to Crashlytics, about 40 % of the users have a continous crash on startup. Following error is reported "Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'Hotel.cityHotelNumber' has been removed.". How can this be, when the schema version has been bumped up?

Comment: What version of Realm do you use?

Comment: I use Realm 2.0.3.

Comment: Did you have a chance to reproduce it by yourself? Can you share some of your migration and models definition code?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I get the same error.